# Would you fix this gap in vinyl siding?

Tags: vinyl-siding

I've been fixing a bunch of cracked siding panels, so I was on a mission to "fix it all". I came across this one (see red circle in picture below). Oddly (to me), unlike the other sides of the structure this side did not use "finish trim" at the top with the siding panels cut to fit up under it. Instead, the siding panels are uncut at the top, but their nail strips are nailed up under a board. So to fix this, I think I'd have to remove the board, replace the siding panel with one that is longer to fill that gap, then re-attach the board.

1) Will this gap cause trouble (water entering, etc.)?

2) Can anyone explain why this side of the structure would be so different from the others in the attachment of the top of the siding?

[image]

Comment: It's been nearly a year, will you come back to let us know what you did? I suspect that the board was put up there to cover some sort of sin in framing or siding...

Comment: @FreeMan I just left it alone as no one seemed to think this was going to cause a problem!

Comment: If you'll accept the given answer or write up your own, then the world will know that this question is resolved. That's helpful - saves people time in looking at old questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That gap could be the result of seasonal movement. If installed correctly, the nails in vinyl siding components are left loose, so that the vinyl can move with daily and seasonal expansion and contraction.

I'd try pulling each section of edge channel sideways to close the gap. You might find that it moves easily.

Comment: It may be that the length of two pieces was just short of full coverage. Do you think there is enough slipped  behind corner trim to make up the GAP?

Comment: I went with the "it's just a small gap that's not hurting anything. no need to fix it" approach.